# Copy images from Jupyter Lab on Mac

Tags: mac, jupyter

Using Jupyter Lab, I have some images output from matplotlib. I would like to copy the image. How can I do this?

Things that do not work:

1. Right-click->Save Image As..., or Copy Image
2. Right-click->Copy Cells
3. Select the image, press Command-C
4. Select the output cell, press Command-C
5. Drag and drop the image (though when you drag it it does correctly show the preview of the image under the mouse cursor).

Comment: Screenshot the image?

Comment: Yeah obviously I had thought of that, but that a) is tedious, b) doesn't get you consistent borders and c) is difficult if you have an image larger than the window.

Comment: Also you don't get transparency (not sure if Mac copy/paste supports that though - Windows definitely doesn't).

Comment: Saw this on SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380569/jupyterlab-how-to-save-a-figure-from-the-notebook - I don't use Jupyter/python so I can't say I've tested it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a solution has been found on a different SO site.

Comment: Funny, I'm surprised the question isn't closed on Stackoverflow because it definitely isn't a "programming question" and they're super-anal about that.

Comment: @Timmmm: It seems like on even-numbered days, [SO] tolerates questions that belong on [SU] and are not programming-related (and on odd-numbered days, they close them, and on prime-numbered days, they migrate the questions here).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

User [foglerit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189418/foglerit) asked [a very similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46380569/1672723),
and posted (and accepted) [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46380569/1672723#46574935):

> I found the answer:
>   the old menu is available by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>
>   while doing a two-fingers click on a Mac,
>   or doing a <kbd>Shift</kbd>+right-click on Linux/Windows
>
> Source: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3043#event-1272299457